# XML schema validation before svn commit

Tags: python, xml, svn, validation, xsd

Is there a possibility in svn to validate an xml file against a schema file before commiting it to the repository? So I can be sure that the file in the repository is reliable.
I already searched for it but i didn't find the answer.
Programming language should be python. I found some articles about "pre-commit hook" but they didn't solve my problem. Maybe i just had a problem in understanding.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pre-commit hook is what you want. So, a an executable Python program named "pre-commit" that lives in your-repo/hooks directory and does validation on committed xml files, returning zero if they pass validation and a non-zero value if they don't.

http://lxml.de/validation.html and http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook should give you enough to go on.